# How to redirect in Nginx from Year/Month/Postname to Year/Month/Category/Postname

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I am using Wordpress on Nginx, and I need to create these 301 redirects:

1. from `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%category%/%postname%/`
2. from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%category%/%postname%/`

How would I do this?

Comment: Write a PHP-script. How would nginx know where to redirect?

Comment: can you elaborate your comment.

Comment: It's not a nginx's job. It's your application's job.

Comment: can you give me hint how do i do this with php in wordpress.

Comment: I'm almost sure there is a wordpress plugin for it.

Comment: You might find some Wordpress specific help on this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

After some searching on web i got the Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin from bellow link which work on redirect old permalink structure to new permalink structure.

You can try both version.

Download link:- http://scott.yang.id.au/pages/permalink-redirect.html